# SQLAlchemy cascade not deleting related object in one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three SQLAlchemy models: `Template`, `Venue`, and `VersionKit`. When I delete a `Venue` instance, the associated `Template` instance is also deleted as expected due to the cascade parameter. However, the associated `VersionKit` instance is not deleted.

```py
class Template(Base):
    __tablename__ = "template"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    version_kit_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("version_kit.id"))

    version_kit = relationship("VersionKit", back_populates="template")
    venue = relationship("Venue", back_populates="template")

class Venue(Base):
    __tablename__ = "venue"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    template_fk = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("template.id"))
    template = relationship("Template", back_populates="venue", cascade="all, delete-orphan", single_parent=True)
    
class VersionKit(Base):
    __tablename__ = "version_kit"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    template = relationship("Template", back_populates="version_kit", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

And here's the function I use to delete a `Venue` instance:

```py
 def delete_venue(self, venue_id, db: Session):
        venue = db.query(Venue).filter(Venue.id == id).first()
        db.delete(venue)
        db.commit()
        return venue
```

What am I missing? Why isn't the associated VersionKit instance deleted automatically when I delete a Venue instance?